# Exchange mailbox discovery

Tags: active-directory, exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2016

**Old situation:** Domain controller AD01, Exchange 2010 server MAIL01 (also domain controller)

**New situation:** Domain Controller AD01, Exchange 2010 migrated to 2016 on new server (MAIL02, no DC anymore), new Domain Controller AD02, MAIL01 removed (following the correct procedures for removing exchange and AD)

**Problem:**

When a user starts outlook for the first time, exchange autodiscovery works fine and the mailbox is configured correctly (autodiscovery is pointing to MAIL02).

However, if you want to add a second mailbox, or if you want to configure an outlook profile manually, you have to enter the mailserver name and the mailbox name. This is where it goes wrong.

In the old situation this worked by filling in MAIL01/username.

When I try now to enter MAIL02/username I get the error:

"*The action cannot be completed. The connection to Microsoft Exchange is unavailable. Outlook must be online or connected to complete this action.*"

(same error on different computers (Win7/10) or outlook versions (2010/2013), doesn't matter if I user FQDN or not).

However, if I enter AD01/username or AD02/username it finds the mailbox and changes the servername automatically to MAIL02 (both server and mailbox become underlined as being correctly recognized).

Is this something new to Exchange 2016 or did I miss something in my configuration?

Comment: First check if the old server is really gone from AD - https://blog.dargel.at/2012/02/23/remove-legacy-exchange-server-using-adsi/ . You could also run get-clientaccessserver and see if there are any references to the old server.

Comment: get-clientaccessserver only returns the new exchange server. Old exchange server still exists in AD as computer object, but exchange has been uninstalled and removed from AD.  I've heard from some other IT experts that MS requires you to use autodiscovery since exchange 2013. Maybe I'm just holding on too much on old habits...

Comment: Did you used something like _Set-CASMailbox kelly.chatir -MAPIBlockOutlookNonCachedMode $true_ and try to configure an Outlook account without Cache mode? Then the error message you outlined above will be shown.